# Unable to load Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.2.0 version assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm getting following error when i try to load 2.2.0 version of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` assembly. My .net core web app is always trying to load `2.1.0` assembly. All assembly references are point to `2.2.0` version. Please find the below load error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

CSPROJ File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Alachisoft.NCache.SDK" Version="4.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Alachisoft.NCache.SessionServices" Version="4.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Alachisoft.NCache.SessionStateProvider" Version="4.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moment.js" Version="2.24.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.MailKit" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Schema" Version="4.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.NetCore" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core" Version="2018.3.1017" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.Windows.Documents.Core" Version="2019.2.612" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.Windows.Documents.Fixed" Version="2019.2.612" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet" Version="2019.2.612" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.OpenXml" Version="2019.2.612" />
    <PackageReference Include="underscore.js" Version="1.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsBase" Version="4.6.1055" />
    <PackageReference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6" Version="1.8.25" />

</Project>
```

Comment: Ware are you having? .NET Core 2.x application? 3.x? some Assembly may have a reference to it, try search in the solution view for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` it shows all packages which have dependendies on it. If .NET Core 2.2 app, do you have .NET Core 2.2 SDK/Runtime installed?

Comment: Can you show your `.csproj` file?

Comment: Thank you for your response Tseng, I've search for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions in solution view but everywhere its showing 2.2.0 version of assembly. I'm using .net core 2.2 assemblies inside .Net framework 4.8 web project.

Comment: @poke Thank you for your response, Here is the package reference in .csproj file    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />

Comment: I've also tried to redirect 2.1.0 assembly to 2.2.0 assembly but still application is trying to load 2.1.0 assembly. <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the full `.csproj` please? Do you reference other projects or packages that may have a reference to 2.1?

Comment: @poke Thank you for your response, I've added the .csproj file, Its too large file which is why i'm unable to share.. I've already verified that its referring the 2.2.0 version in all projects of the solution. Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Ensure that your all of your csproj files are using `<PackageReference>` project instead of package.config model. This problem usually happened wheh you are using old package.config model.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono - Thank you for your response, I'm using <PackageRefrence> in the .csproj file to add packages instead of package.config. The target framework of the web project is 4.8, And we are referring .Net core 2.2 libraries in it.

Comment: Btw. note that support for .NET Core 2.2 components ends on December 23, 2019, and that you won’t be able to upgrade to 3.0 on .NET Framework. You will have to downgrade to 2.1 for continued support on .NET Framework.